# Why is my carefully designed to be "not-optional" return value being treated like an optional?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to extract the earliest (and latest, but since the two methods are going to be nearly identical, I'll concentrate on "earliest" for this question) date held in a global `DataSource` object, `theData`, and return it *as a NON-OPTIONAL value*.

`DataSource` is a "souped up Array" object holding an arbitrary number of `DataEntry` objects. Here's the bare-bones of the definition of `DataEntry`:

```
class DataEntry: Codable, Comparable {
    var theDate: Date = Date() // To avoid using an optional but still silence compiler
                               // complaints about no initializer
    // Lots of other properties and support code irrelevant to the question snipped for brevity.
}
```

Retrieving the needed date(s) is done as a method of my `DataSource` class:

```
class DataSource: Codable {
var theArray: [DataEntry] = Array()

// Several hundred lines of non-relevant support and convenience code chopped

// Return either .theDate from the earliest DataEntry held in theArray, or Date() 
// if theArray.first hands back a nil (indicating theArray is unpopulated).
// Either way, I specifically want the returned value to *NOT* be an optional!
func earliest() -> Date {
    // First, make certain theArray is sorted ascending by .theDate
    theArray.sort {
        $0.theDate < $1.theDate
    }
    // Now that we know theArray is in order, theArray.first?.theDate is the earliest stored date 
    // - If it exists.
    // But since .first hands back an optional, and I specifically DO NOT WANT an optional return from 
    // .earliest(), I nil-coalesce to set firstDate to Date() as needed.

    let firstDate: Date = theArray.first?.theDate ?? Date()
    print("firstDate = \(firstDate)")
    return firstDate
}

func latest() -> Date {
    // gutted for brevity - mostly identical to .earliest()
    return lastDate
}
}
```

Note that I take pains to make sure what gets returned ***is not*** an optional. And, in fact, later code blows up if I try to treat it like it could be:

```
class SelectDateRangeViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var startPicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var endPicker: UIDatePicker!

// Irrelevant code elided

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let e = theData.earliest()
    // Note: Changing the previous line to 
    // let e = theData.earliest()!   
    // gets a compile-time error: "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Date'"                      
    let l = theData.latest()
    // We should now have the earliest and latest dates in theData held in e and l, respectively.
    // Print them to the debugger console to verify they're actually what I expect...
    print ("e = \(e)")
    print ("l = \(l)")
    // ...and carry on
    startPicker.minimumDate = e // <--- Crashes here, claiming that I've tried to implicitly unwrap an optional value! See the console log dump below
    startPicker.maximumDate = l
    startPicker.date = e

    endPicker.minimumDate = e
    endPicker.maximumDate = l
    endPicker.date = l
    }
 }
```

What follows is what I see in the debugger console when I try to run the "actual code" (rather than the gutted-to-save-space version presented here)

---start debugger log

firstDate = 2020-04-16 15:00:31 +0000   <---- This line and the next come from inside the .earliest()/.latest() methods of DataSource

lastDate = 2020-04-27 15:43:23 +0000

e = 2020-04-16 15:00:31 +0000   <---- And these two lines come from the viewWillAppear() method shown above.

l = 2020-04-27 15:43:23 +0000

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /ActualPathRemoved/SelectDateRangeViewController.swift, line ##

--- end debugger log

Where the ## in that crash line is the actual line number occupied by the "startPicker.minimumDate = e" statement in the "all of the code is there" version.

The values displayed as "firstDate", "lastDate", "e", and "l" are *ABSOLUTELY CORRECT* for the test dataset I'm using.

But wait a minute! The compiler says that the return from .earliest() *is not* an optional when I try to force-unwrap it! And since when is a perfectly valid Date object "nil"??? And why is the code trying to "implicitly unwrap" a non-nil, not-optional value?!?!? Somebody make up my mind!

So what am I misunderstanding? Either my code is hosed, or what I understood while trying to write it is. Which is the case, and what's the problem???

Answer to @Paulw11's comment query:

```
@IBAction func reportRequestButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let theVC = SelectDateRangeViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(theVC, animated: true)        
}
```

This bit of code lives in the viewController that offers the button as part of a scene that offers a menu of "let the user tinker with the dataset in various ways" buttons. When first added, I intended to bring up the SelectRangeScene with a segue, but for some reason, decided that pushing it onto the UINavigationController stack would be a better way of doing it, though I can't remember why it was I thought that now - the reason apparently got shaken loose and lost while I was beating my head against the problem of why trying to set the datepickers was crashing.

Comment: How did you create this view controller instance?  A common mistake is not creating the instance from the storyboard resulting in the outlets not being bound. You can't get a `nil` exception from `e` as it isn't an implicitly unwrapped optional (it isn't optional at all, as you say), therefore it is the picker outlet that is `nil`. Also, from a style point of view I would make `earliest` and `latest` computed properties instead of functions and return `.distantPast` and `.distantFuture` from your nil coalescing operator rather than the current date.

Comment: As I suspected, you are just instantiating your view controller rather than getting the instance from your storyboard. This means that all of your outlets will be `nil`

Comment: Swift is very shadowy; `the` is discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your new view controller instance with

```
let theVC = SelectDateRangeViewController()
```

Since you don't get the instance from the storyboard, none of the outlets are bound; they will be `nil`.  As your outlets are declared as implicitly unwrapped optionals, you get a crash when you refer to them.

You could instantiate the new view controller from your storyboard but it would probably be simpler to use a segue either directly from your button or by using `performSegue` in your `@IBAction`

Comment: Trying doing it different... There was a reason I decided not to go with a segue, but I can't recall what that reason was now. Trying it as `let theVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectDateRangeScene") as! SelectDateRangeViewController` and pushing that... will see if that cures things in a shortly... And there it is! Doing just what it should be doing. Beautiful!

Comment: Yes, that is what you need if you want a VC from a  storyboard without a segue

Answer (score 3):

If the code crashes in this line then the `startPicker` outlet is not connected.

It has nothing to do with the dates, they are definitely non-optional.

Comment: Checking... Nope. Both UIDatePickers are indeed showing as connected from the storyboard. As a "belt-and-suspenders" check, I deleted both connections, saved both the SelectDateRangeViewController.swift file and the main.storyboard file, quit XCode, restarted it, opened the project, and re-connected them before trying a new run. No change. The only visible differences are the timestamps. (not the dates being retrieved - those are exactly the same - the debugger-inserted timestamps showing when the run started and when the crash happened)

Comment: Use the debugger. Set the exception breakpoint and figure out what is `nil`.

Comment: Looks like you're correct, though I can't see how - Both of the datePickers are indeed nil when I breakpoint on the `startPicker.minimumDate = e` line and examine things, even though they both show as properly connected when I look at them in the storyboard, and when I click on the connection markers in the controller code, I'm offered the appropriate picker in the storyboard. Something's weird here...